# QuTiP ptrace function results do not recreate original composite system

Tags: programming, linear-algebra, qutip

I have a qutip density matrix `fullsystem` for a system composed of two quantum systems with `dims = [[n, n], [n, n]], shape = (n**2, n**2)`. It's my understanding that if I wanted the density matrix of each system separately, I could do

```python
subsystem1 = fullsystem.ptrace(0)
subsystem2 = fullsystem.ptrace(1)
```

Should I not be able to get `fullsystem` back by doing `tensor(subsystem1, subsystem2)`? This is not working for me `(fullsystem == tensor(subsystem1, subsystem2)` gives False), they are close but significantly more different than I'd expect. I have tried `tensor(susbsystem1.unit(), subsystem2.unit())` as well.

Am I just not understanding how I should be using `ptrace`? Are there certain assumptions about `fullsystem` that I need to take into account beyond knowing the two subsystem composition given by `dims`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would only work if `fullsystem` is a product state.

Let $\rho$ be your full system. For example, say

$$\rho = |011\rangle\langle011|\,.\tag{1}$$

Now,

$$\rho_1 = \text{Tr}_{23}\big[\rho\big] = |0\rangle\langle0|\,,\tag{2.1}$$
$$\rho_{23} = \text{Tr}_{1}\big[\rho\big] = |11\rangle\langle11|\,.\tag{2.2}$$

So in this case, $$\rho = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_{23}\,,\tag{3}$$
is true. However, this will not be true if your $\rho$ has entanglement.

---

Let's perform the same analysis programatically using `QuTiP`.

Creating $\rho$:

```python
# Define basis states for 3 qubits
q0 = basis(2, 0)  # |0⟩
q1 = basis(2, 1)  # |1⟩
psi = tensor(q0, q1, q1) # Example 3-qubit state: |0⟩ ⊗ |1⟩ ⊗ |1⟩

# Creating a density matrix from the state |0⟩ ⊗ |1⟩ ⊗ |1⟩
rho = psi * psi.dag()
# Print the density matrix
print("Density Matrix:")
print(rho)
```

This gives output:

```
Density Matrix:
Quantum object: dims = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]], shape = (8, 8), type = oper, isherm = True
Qobj data =
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Now, taking the partial trace and computing $\rho_1$ and $\rho_{23}$:

```python
# Performing partial trace for the first qubit
rho_1 = ptrace(rho, [0])
print("\nPartial Trace for the first qubit:")
print(rho_1)


# Performing partial trace for the second and third qubit
rho_23 = ptrace(rho, [1, 2])
print("\nPartial Trace for the second and third qubit:")
print(rho_23)
```

This gives output:

```
Partial Trace for the first qubit:
Quantum object: dims = [[2], [2]], shape = (2, 2), type = oper, isherm = True
Qobj data =
[[1. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]

Partial Trace for the second and third qubit:
Quantum object: dims = [[2, 2], [2, 2]], shape = (4, 4), type = oper, isherm = True
Qobj data =
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

And now, let's check if Eq.$(\text{3})$ holds true or not.

```python
rho == tensor(rho_1, rho_23)
```

This gives output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks, some basic QM I gotta go back and review :P